# API call and observer on customer creation

Tags: magento2.3

I want to create an **observer** when a new customer is registered through the REST API (**POST /rest/V1/customers**). I have created an observer `customer_register_success` but it's only been triggered when a registration takes place from the website and not from the API call. Is it the correct behavior?

Should I create an observer for another event like `customer_save_after`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is provided to run events on area wise.

Here

the area code of respective Area

```
Area | Area Code

Frontend | frontend

Admin Section | adminhtml

Web Api  area for soap | webapi_soap

Web Api area for Rest|webapi_rest`
```

As you want to  fire the event for API area then  create events.xml below two folders

`app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/etc/webapi_rest`
`app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/etc/webapi_soap`

Then the observer writes on these two events.xml files only run for API area.

Comment: I've noticed that customer_save_after event is always fired both from form and from API but customer_register_success is only fired from the registration form. Is it because customer register_success is defined inside app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php  ??

Comment: yes, customer_register_success defined at createpost.php

Comment: Is there any other event I can use? I want to observe registration from API and save some custom customer attributes after calling some 3rd party API, inside the observer. I cannot use customer_save_after because I end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried.it should not be loop side the observer

Comment: I have an observer customer_save_after to be fired when a customer is registered from the magento API. Inside the observer I'm calling a 3rd party API and update customer's custom field with a value that I'm getting from the 3rd party API, by using $customer->setData('code', $code);$customer->save(); So the observer is fired again and again

Comment: You don't need to add `save()` method.Just add `$customer->setData('code', $code);`